# RE-deployment of a SQL server job returns The specified @name ('') already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs, sql-agent-job

I created a job to be run once a day. The script for the job will be deployed as a part of post script in visual studio.
First time deployment went fine and the job was deployed out successfully, but when I try to deploy again I get the error that the job already exists: my code looks like the following:

```
 USE [msdb]
 GO


BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE 
name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', 
@name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'test', 
    @enabled=1, 
    @notify_level_eventlog=2, 
    @notify_level_email=0, 
    @notify_level_netsend=0, 
    @notify_level_page=0, 
    @delete_level=0, 
    @description=N'EXEC [dbo].[test]', 
    @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
    @owner_login_name=N'XXXXX', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
 IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

 EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, 
    @step_name=N'test', 
    @step_id=1, 
    @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
    @on_success_action=1, 
    @on_success_step_id=0, 
    @on_fail_action=2, 
    @on_fail_step_id=0, 
    @retry_attempts=0, 
    @retry_interval=0, 
    @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
    @command=N'exec  [dbo].[test]', 
    @database_name=N'BAC', 
    @output_file_name=N'H:\database_Clean', 
    @flags=14
   IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
   EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, 
   @start_step_id = 1
   IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
    EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, 
     @name=N'test', 
    @enabled=1, 
    @freq_type=8, 
    @freq_interval=1, 
    @freq_subday_type=1, 
    @freq_subday_interval=0, 
    @freq_relative_interval=0, 
    @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
    @active_start_date=20200130, 
    @active_end_date=99991231, 
    @active_start_time=22000, 
    @active_end_time=235959, 
    @schedule_uid=N'14301302-23af-424e-9a11-409cbfc0dddc'
    IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
    EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, 
   @server_name = N'(local)'
   IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
   COMMIT TRANSACTION
   GOTO EndSave
   QuitWithRollback:
   IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   EndSave:
   GO
```

I actually check if the job exists with the following script:

```
  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.sysoperators WHERE name=N'test')
```

But still it gives me the same error:

```
  Msg 14261, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_verify_job, Line 57 [Batch Start Line 13]
  The specified @name ('test') already exists.
```

I checked the following question [@name already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60053153/sql-server-sp-verify-job-name-already-exists) which has the same issue, but the answer was to delete the job and then deploy. I don't want to delete the job it should just check if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.sysoperators WHERE name=N'test')
```

This does not check if the job `test` exists, it checks if the operator `test` exists.

You want

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name=N'test')
```

So your full code would be

```
USE [msdb]
 GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE name=N'test')
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
    SELECT @ReturnCode = 0

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE 
    name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
    BEGIN
    EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', 
    @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
    IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

    END

    DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
    EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'test', 
       @enabled=1, 
       @notify_level_eventlog=2, 
       @notify_level_email=0, 
       @notify_level_netsend=0, 
       @notify_level_page=0, 
       @delete_level=0, 
       @description=N'EXEC [dbo].[test]', 
       @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
       @owner_login_name=N'XXXXX', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
    IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

    EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, 
       @step_name=N'test', 
       @step_id=1, 
       @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
       @on_success_action=1, 
       @on_success_step_id=0, 
       @on_fail_action=2, 
       @on_fail_step_id=0, 
       @retry_attempts=0, 
       @retry_interval=0, 
       @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
       @command=N'exec  [dbo].[test]', 
       @database_name=N'BAC', 
       @output_file_name=N'H:\database_Clean', 
       @flags=14
      IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
      EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, 
      @start_step_id = 1
      IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
       EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, 
        @name=N'test', 
       @enabled=1, 
       @freq_type=8, 
       @freq_interval=1, 
       @freq_subday_type=1, 
       @freq_subday_interval=0, 
       @freq_relative_interval=0, 
       @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
       @active_start_date=20200130, 
       @active_end_date=99991231, 
       @active_start_time=22000, 
       @active_end_time=235959, 
       @schedule_uid=N'14301302-23af-424e-9a11-409cbfc0dddc'
       IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
       EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, 
      @server_name = N'(local)'
      IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
      COMMIT TRANSACTION
      GOTO EndSave
      QuitWithRollback:
      IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      EndSave:
END
```

Comment: I changed according to your recommendation but I get the following error :

Comment: Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_verify_job_identifiers, Line 25 [Batch Start Line 3]
Supply either job_id or job_name to identify the job.

Comment: Can you update your question with your full code. Your original code doesn't seem to reference that stored procedure anywhere

Comment: See amended answer